# Is Aramaic "bar enos," "son of man," identifiable as a definite or indefinite form?

Tags: grammar, aramaic

In the written NT, "the son of man" is "ο γιος του ανθρώπου," with a definite article "ο." This would presumably be a Greek translation of an Aramaic phrase used during the apostolic period (unless a Greek-speaking evangelist invented its usage as a title out of whole cloth), and would have been familiar to first-century Palestinian Jews as a stock phrase heard in readings of the then-oral targums (e.g., Daniel 7:13).

I don't know any Aramaic, but I gather that in Aramaic this is "bar enos," and as far as I can tell from looking at a description of the grammar, the meaning that is conveyed in English or Greek by a definite article is indicated in Aramaic by a suffix "-a."

So if an Aramaic speaker wanted to say "*the* son of man," would they have said something like "bara enos?" Or would the "-a" go away because of the following vowel or something like that?

The point here is whether there would have been any distinction apparent in oral Aramaic between "[a] son of man" and the title "the Son of Man." (I gather that Koine Greek had definite articles but no indefinite articles.)

Some linguistic information about the phrase in Aramaic: https://www.goarch.org/-/the-aramaic-phrase-bar-enos-son-of-man-dan-7-13-14-revisited

Comment: What evidence do you have that this expression is 'a Greek translation for an Aramaic phrase' ? Koine Greek has 'an article'. It does not have a 'definite article'.

Comment: @NigelJ: Not clear on your question. Are you not convinced that Jesus and his followers all spoke Aramaic to each other? Are you not convinced that Jesus ever referred to himself as "the son of man?"

Comment: Koine Greek was the _lingua franca_ of the Mediterranean region. The apostles would have been fluent in Koine Greek, possibly as their own language or maybe bi-lingual. There is no evidence to suppose that one has to look deeper than the actual words they wrote in order to understand their concepts. To do so, is to undermine the gift of the scriptures to humanity.

Comment: . . .  in any case, this quiestion is off-topic as it is not focused on a text of scripture but is opening up a topic for debate. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the functioning and purpose of the site and in particular the matter of 'biblical topic' questions being off-topic on an hermeneutic site.

Comment: @Ben you can fix the problem with your question by tying it to specific New Testament  passages such as John 5:27 and contrasting it with Daniel 7:13.

Comment: @Ben. Have a look here: https://www.jerusalemperspective.com/2471/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hebrew and Aramaic a noun in the construct drops the definite article.  An example is בֶּן־יִשַׁי֙ *ben Jishay* "the son of Jesse" in 1 Samuel 20:31.  *Ben* in Hebrew is in construct and translated "the son of" although it has no article because it is construct.

Daniel 7:13 has  *k-bar eneysh* as a/the son of man.  The Septuagint (LXX) translates it without the article ὡς υἱὸς ἀνθρώπου.

There are two possible reasons a New Testament writer would use the article in Greek.

1. They interpreted the construct has having the article.
2. However, especially when alluding to Daniel 7:13, the more likely reason is the article points specifically to "son of man" in Daniel (e.g. John 5:27) as apposed to the meaning any human, or human likeness as in Revelation 1:13